# JQuery classname selector starting with?

Tags: jquery

I have the folowing html markup:

```
<DIV class="bubble bubble_white">
  <DIV class=bubble_large></DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="bubble bubble_black">
  <DIV class=bubble_large></DIV>
</DIV>
```

I want to select the classes `bubble bubble_white` and `bubble bubble_black`. I was thinking about the code underneath but it didn't work:

`$(".bubble.[class^=bubble_]")`

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".bubble[class*=bubble_]")
```

Comment: Note that this will also match something like “foobubble_bar”.

Answer (score 6):

The `[attr^=val]` selector is comparing the whole attribute value. So your attribute value must begin with `bubble_` to be selected. For a whitespace-separated list, you could use the `[attr|=val]` selector:

```
$(".bubble[class|=bubble_white], .bubble[class|=bubble_black]")
```

Or you do the filtering on your own:

```
$(".bubble").filter("[class|=bubble_white], [class|=bubble_black]")
```

Or:

```
$(".bubble").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.hasClass("bubble_white") || $this.hasClass("bubble_black");
})
```

Or:

```
$(".bubble").filter(function() {
    return /(?:^|\s+)bubble_/.test(this.className);
})
```